# Partial derivatives chart-dependent?

Tags: complex-analysis, manifolds, partial-derivative, riemann-surfaces, complex-manifolds

Let $X$ be a Riemann surface. Let $Y\subset X$ be open.

The following definitions are taken from page 60 of Forster's *Riemann Surfaces*.
We call a function $f\colon Y \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ *(infinitely) differentiable on $Y$* if for every chart $z\colon U \rightarrow V \subset \mathbb{C}$ on $X$ with $U\subset Y$ there exists an (infinitely) real-differentiable function $\tilde{f}\colon V \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with $f\restriction_{U}=\tilde{f}\circ z$.
Denote the set of differentiable functions on $Y$ by $\mathcal{E}(Y)$.

Now, let $z_1=x_1+i y_1$ be a chart of $X$ on $U$. With respect to this chart, we define operators $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y_1}\colon \mathcal{E}(Y)\rightarrow \mathcal{E}(Y)$ by setting $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}\colon = \frac{\partial (f\circ z_1^{-1})}{\partial x}\circ z_1$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_1}\colon = \frac{\partial (f\circ z_1^{-1})}{\partial y}\circ z_1$ for $f\in \mathcal{E}(Y)$.
Here, for a given $g\colon V\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, the symbol $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ denotes the usual partial derivative, i.e. $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x} u(x,y) + i \frac{\partial}{\partial x} v(x,y)$ where $g=u(x,y)+i\cdot v(x,y)$.

Now to my question: Is this definition of partial derivatives independent of charts?

Comment: I think there's a typo in your question: you should have $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$ instead of $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ in the definition of $\frac{\partial \tilde{f}}{\partial x}$ right?

Comment: Yes, thanks! Your answer solves my confusion.

Comment: I changed the definition of the operators slightly. Forster only writes *the differential operators $\frac{\partial}{\partial x},…\colon \mathcal{E}(U)\rightarrow \mathcal{E}(U)$ can be defined in the obvious way*. I think was missing precomposition with $z_1$ before. Otherwise $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ would not map into $\mathcal{E}(U)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they depend on the chart.
For instance, let $M = \Bbb C$ be the complex manifold $\Bbb C$ thought abstractly.
Consider the two global holomorphic charts
$$
z_1 \colon z \in M \mapsto z_1(z) = z \in \Bbb C \quad \text{and} \quad
z_2 \colon z \in M \mapsto z_2(z) = 2z \in \Bbb C,
$$
and let's write $z_1 = x_1+ iy_1$ and $z_2 = x_2 + iy_2$.
Let $f\colon M \to \Bbb C$ be the identity map.
Then
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} := \frac{\partial (f\circ z_1^{-1})}{\partial x} = 1,
$$
but
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} := \frac{\partial (f\circ z_2^{-1})}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{2}.
$$
What is independent of the chart is their differentiable properties, and that the partial derivatives satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations in one complex chart if and only if they satisfy it in the other.

However, they are related by a simple formula, relying on the chain rule:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} = \frac{\partial (f\circ z_2^{-1})}{\partial x} 
= \frac{\partial \left((f\circ z_1^{-1}) \circ (z_1\circ z_2^{-1}) \right)}{\partial x} 
= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} \cdot \frac{\partial (z_1\circ z_2^{-1})}{\partial x}.
$$
Indeed, here, $\dfrac{\partial (z_1\circ z_2^{-1})}{\partial x} = \dfrac{\partial (\frac{1}{2}z)}{\partial x} = \dfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @peterfreed I've added something that I think might be valuable

Comment: This is indeed valuable: It shows that both partial derivatives with respect to one chart vanish at a point $a\in X$  iff they vanish at $a\in X$ with respect to another chart. Thus, the vector space of those function germs which vanish to second order can be defined as it is. We can build the cotangent space of $X$ at $a\in X$ from there.

Comment: By the way, do you call $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ the *partial derivative of $f$ with respect to the component $x$ of the chart $z=x+iy$*?

Comment: @PeterFreed I would call it the first partial derivative of $f$ in the chart $z$.